# how to zoom in to a sprite in bevy

Tags: camera, rendering, bevy

I wanted to implement zooming in my 2d bevy game. After some code browsing I found out that `Camera2dBundle` uses `OrthographicProjection` by default and can not zoom in as required.

I tried using `Camera`**3**`dBundle` which does define `projection: PerspectiveProjection` by default but my sprite seems to disappear from the scene.

Could you give me some pointers to what I'm doing wrong? I have included some test code below.

Thanks

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .add_system(zoom_in)
        .run();
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands
    ) {
        commands.spawn_bundle(Camera3dBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0., 0., 1000.).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Z),
            ..Default::default()
        });
        
        commands.spawn_bundle(SpriteBundle {
           sprite: Sprite { custom_size: Some(Vec2 { x: 50., y: 50. }), ..Default::default()},
           ..Default::default()
        });
}

pub fn zoom_in(mut query: Query<&mut Transform, With<Camera>>, time: Res<Time>) {
    for mut transform in query.iter_mut() {
        transform.translation.z -= 100. * time.delta_seconds();

        warn!("{}", transform.translation.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not see the sprite, because you apparently look at it from the wrong side. If you have a 2D scene I would advise you to stick to the [`Camera2DBundle`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.8.1/bevy/core_pipeline/prelude/struct.Camera2dBundle.html).

Contrary to what you stated in your question, in order to zoom you can set the [`scale`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.8.1/bevy/render/camera/struct.OrthographicProjection.html#structfield.scale) of [`OrthographicProjection`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.8.1/bevy/render/camera/struct.OrthographicProjection.html) like so:

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .add_system(zoom_in)
        .run();
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands
    ) {
        commands.spawn_bundle(Camera2dBundle::default());
        commands.spawn_bundle(SpriteBundle {
           sprite: Sprite { custom_size: Some(Vec2 { x: 50., y: 50. }), ..Default::default()},
           ..Default::default()
        });
}

pub fn zoom_in(mut query: Query<&mut OrthographicProjection, With<Camera>>, time: Res<Time>) {
    for mut projection in query.iter_mut() {
        projection.scale -= 0.1 * time.delta_seconds();

        println!("Current zoom scale: {}", projection.scale);
    }
}
```

Note that you might want to implement [logarithmic zoom](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/logarithmic-interpolation), so that your zoom does "feel" linear and does not speed up approaching infinity when the scale approaches zero.

Here is a sample using logarithmic zoom:

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .add_system(zoom_in)
        .run();
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands
    ) {
        commands.spawn_bundle(Camera2dBundle::default());
        commands.spawn_bundle(SpriteBundle {
           sprite: Sprite { custom_size: Some(Vec2 { x: 50., y: 50. }), ..Default::default()},
           ..Default::default()
        });
}

pub fn zoom_in(mut query: Query<&mut OrthographicProjection, With<Camera>>, time: Res<Time>) {
    for mut projection in query.iter_mut() {
        let mut log_scale = projection.scale.ln();
        log_scale -= 0.1 * time.delta_seconds();
        projection.scale = log_scale.exp();

        println!("Current zoom scale: {}", projection.scale);
    }
}
```